# What happened to this character's body in OUAT Season 7 finale?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

(wanted to avoid spoilers so I was vague)

This is about one episode away from the finale: Wish Realm Rumple stabs Samdi in front of Real Rumple with the Dark One dagger.  This happens in Samdi's mansion and the episode ends there.  In the next episode, Regina enters the mansion and finds RR trapped there.  There is no sign of either WRR or Samdi.  RR then tells Regina that Samdi is dead.  When they all go to WRR's castle, Samdi's body is never seen.

I thought at first that Samdi would still be alive because a) he knew voodoo stuff so maybe he could have survived being stabbed and b) no body is usually an indicator that the character is still alive, ex. a character being "vaporized" when in reality they were transported, you know?  A character with a body show is usually really dead.

So, **What did WRR do with Samdi's body?**  Did he just take it with him and toss it down a hole?  He doesn't bother taking RR with him even though at this point RR really does need to be detained.  Why would WRR not just leave the body there?  Or did something happen to it?  Did the Dark One dagger cause his body to dissolve or transport or something?  Probably not, I know, but this season had a character being saved by having someone else's heart thrust inside them so it seems like all bets are off with season 7 magic.